# Find Regex Pattern From Inputs

Tags: regex

I have a user access log like this:

```
pagename    url
broker_pv   /broker/934832
broker_pv   /broker/983432
broker_pv   /broker/n/342349
listing_pv  /listing/a1-b2/
listing_pv  /listing/c3/
```

I want to find out whether a future url "/broker/245729" belongs to "broker_pv" or "listing_pv", or doesn't match at all.

It's like a machine learning process: I feed the computer some raw data, it learns, and then help me filtering things.

One way to do it, I can think of, is a "pattern finder" process. i.e., from the raw input, we human can deduce that "broker_pv" urls will match a pattern "/broker/(n/)?[0-9]+". So when a url like "/broker/245729" comes, I can test all the patterns against it, and judge which "pagename" it belongs to.

Then the question is, how to find out these patterns and thus build up a "pagename-pattern pair collection" for further use.

Or there's a better way, hopefully?

Comment: You might want to use a strpos() function on '/broker/' first, and if that matches use the regex. Is more lightweight, regexes are slower

Comment: @Jerry sorry, but i really don't understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @user2141046 Basically I want the machine to find out the relationship between "pagename" and "urls", so when a new "url" comes, it'll know which "pagename" it belongs to.

Comment: you can use perl hashes for this, something like `if (!%hash(url)) {%hash(url) = pagename}`. if each pagename has more than one url attached to it, you will need a more sophisticated database to hold it (ages ago i implemented something similar with java - hash of linked lists, should work here as well). please note that slash (/) has special meaning in some regex languages and you might need to place backslash(\) before it.

Comment: @user2141046 Thanks for your reply, but I don't think it's practical. The number after "/broker/" is actually an auto-generated ID, so your approach is to build a hash that has tens of thousands of keys. That's why I need a mechanism to identify the pattern "/broker/[0-9]+" to store as the key for all urls like "/broker/23432", "/broker/73943", etc.

Comment: @Jerry ok, i think i understand you now: you want the `/<name>/#` and all other `/<same name>/<different#>`s to be connected as one and all pointing at the same pagename. am i correct?